# How to upload files in Json format only-EXTJS

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

Is there any way to configure the uploading format only in JSON and restrict any other file type.
So far Im using simple js to upload the file:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload/image" method="post">
    <input id="image-file" type="file" />
</form>
```

but is there an option for only JSN format files to be uploaded and throw error may be for other file types.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use accept attribute on input element:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload/image" method="post">
    <input id="image-file" type="file" accept="application/json" />
</form>
```